# DocuSign demo account and ability to use the API

Tags: docusignapi

Have a question about some of the account and user settings I am seeing from a demo account that I setup to start developing and testing some integrations via the API. I am using the API Explorer provided by DocuSign to check the settings on the account/user that we want to use for the API user in the integration. What I am seeing is that `canSendAPIRequests` is `FALSE` and `usesAPI` is `FALSE` (see below). Does this mean I cannot use this account/user for API calls and if so, what do I need to do to enable it to be used for API calls? Thanks.

I run "Get User Settings" which shows (this is a partial snippet):

```
{
  "name": "canSendAPIRequests",
  "value": "false"
},
{
  "name": "apiAccountWideAccess",
  "value": "true"
}
```

As well as "Get login information" which shows (this is a partial snippet):

```
 {"loginAccountSettings": [
    {
      "name": "usesAPI",
      "value": "false"
    }
  ],
  "loginUserSettings": [
    {
      "name": "canManageAccount",
      "value": "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "canSendAPIRequests",
      "value": "false"
    },
    {
      "name": "canSendEnvelope",
      "value": "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "allowSendOnBehalfOf",
      "value": "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "apiAccountWideAccess",
      "value": "true"
    },
    {
      "name": "allowRecipientLanguageSelection",
      "value": "true"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure why your account would have those settings disabled, especially if you created directly from the Dev Center, but have you tried setting them back?  Try making a `PUT` call on your account settings:

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/settings

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "userSettings": [
    {
      "name": "sting",
      "value": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the call in the REST API documentation:

[Modify User Account Settings](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20Account%20Settings.htm)